# How do I parse a JSON in Haskell where the name of the fields can be one of multiple values, but should be converted into a single Haskell type?

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

Let's say I have the following JSON values.

```
{
  "fieldName1": 5,
  "value1": "Hello"
}
```

and

```
{
  "fieldName2": 7,
  "value1": "Welcome"
}
```

I have the following type in Haskell.

```
data Greeting 
  = Greeting
      {
        count :: Int,
        name :: Text
      }
  deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)
```

How do I parse this JSON into Haskell where `fieldName1` or `fieldName2` values should be parsed as `count` value?

I tried to solve this by doing something like shown below.

```
instance FromJSON Greeting where
  parseJSON = withObject "Greeting" $ \obj -> do
    count1 <- obj .:? "fieldName1"
    count2 <- obj .:? "fieldName2"
    name <- obj .: "value1"
    count <-
      case (count1, count2) of
        (Just count, Nothing) -> return count
        (Nothing, Just count) -> return count
        _ -> fail $ Text.unpack "Field missing"
    return Greeting {count = count, name = name}
```

It works but is very cumbersome and if there are more than 2 alternative values, it becomes a lot more complex. Is there any way to solve this in a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Parser` monad where `parseJSON` runs is itself an `Alternative`, so you can use the alternation `(<|>)` operator within the parser definition:

```
instance FromJSON Greeting where
  parseJSON = withObject "Greeting" $ \o -> do
    Greeting <$> (o .: "fieldName1" <|> o .: "fieldName2"
                  <|> fail "no count field")
             <*> o .: "value1"
```

If multiple "count" fields are present, this will take the first one that parses.

If you want to process field names more programmatically (for example, if you want to accept a single field whose name starts with the prefix `"field"` while rejecting cases with multiple matching fields), then note that `o` is a `KeyMap` that can be processed with the functions in the `Data.Aeson.KeyMap` and `Data.Aeson.Key` modules:

```
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Aeson.Key as Key
import qualified Data.Aeson.KeyMap as KeyMap
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)

instance FromJSON Greeting where
  parseJSON = withObject "Greeting" $ \o -> do
    -- get all values for "field*" keys
    let fields = [v | (k, v) <- KeyMap.toList o
                    , "field" `isPrefixOf` Key.toString k]
    case fields of
      [v] -> Greeting <$> parseJSON v <*> o .: "value1"
      []  -> fail "no \"field*\" fields"
      _   -> fail "multiple \"field*\" fields"
```

Comment: This solves my current issue, but I am curious if it is possible to parse a JSON where I don't know the exact field names. Lets say I only know that any json field which contains the word `field` should be mapped to count in Haskell, how would I parse that?

Comment: I've added a note about one possible approach.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly better variant:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

instance FromJSON Greeting where
  parseJSON = withObject "Greeting" $ \obj -> do
    count1 <- obj .:? "fieldName1"
    count2 <- obj .:? "fieldName2"
    name <- obj .: "value1"
    count <- maybe
       (fail $ Text.unpack "Field missing") -- fail case
       return                               -- success case
       (count1 <|> count2)                  -- take the first success
    return Greeting {count = count, name = name}
```

Essentially, `c1 <|> ... <|> cn` is the first `Just` if there is one, and `Nothing` otherwise.

You can also use `case of` instead of `maybe`, if you prefer. If this is frequently used, I'd put `maybe (fail $ ...) return` in a separate definition, so to give it a nice name.